# parent properties for application-{profile}.properties with Spring-Boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot

There are common properties which are shared among different profiles for e.g. path location for temp files and path remains same among different env(tst,prd).

Is there a way to have a parent application-{parent}.properties from which all the profile specific properties files can inherit the properties.

That will help in avoiding writing same properties in all application-{profile}.properties

In addition, each `application-{profile}.properties` have something like :

```
profileLocation=xxx
abc=${profileLocation}/tempPath
```

Here can I move abc to a common location? I cannot in `application.properties` as it gets loaded before application-{profile}.properties

Comment: That is what the `application.properties` is for... That is loaded first then the profile specific one...

Comment: that is correct. It works as is. Thank you M. Deinum

Comment: Now the properties are same however prefix is profile specific. e.g. ${profile-specific-basePath}/tempLocation. How can I achieve this as profile-specific properties are loaded later than application.properties

Comment: Everything is merged into one large object so not sure what you are trying to achieve that isn't working? If it is always profile specific then remove it from the application.properties, also maybe you want to clarify your question as you are now basically asking a different question...

Comment: updated the question to include the second question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, that is not entirely true that **application.properties** are loaded before any others. They are processed together. To set common properties that are used by all profiles, you should use the ordinary **application.properties** file. Two main thing you should know are described below.

**Case 1.** The keys that are placed inside the **application.properties** file can be overridden by profile specific configuration.

```
common.path.for.all.envs=/some/path
default.path=/another/path
```

Than in your e.g. **application-dev.properties** you can override some values.

```
default.path=/dev/path
```

At runtime with **dev profile** your application will have access to two keys. The value of `common.path.for.all.envs` will be set to `/some/path` as declared only in the main file and `default.path` will be set to `/dev/path` because you override the property in the profile configuration.

**Case 2.** The values defines in the **application.properties** file can use placeholders for the values included in profile configurations. For instance, in your **application.properties** define the following variable:

```
abc=${profileLocation}/tempPath
```

Next, in the **application-dev.properties** declare the missing variable:

```
profileLocation=xxx
```

Then running with the **dev profile** the value of `abc` will be set to `xxx/tempPath`. As you see, the variable declared in the profile configuration can be used in the main **application.properties** file as well.